# Why Compiler doesn't give error when we assign Integer to int in Java

Tags: java

Why compiler doesn't give error when we assign Integer(object) to int(primitive)?

```
int i;
Integer ii = new Integer(5);
i = ii;//no compilation error.
```

And this is the case with all other types(byte-Byte, float-Float)..

What is the reason? Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's called autoboxing/unboxing.

As of Java 1.5, the compiler automatically "boxes" primitives into their corresponding class (eg `int` and `Integer`, `double` and `Double` etc), and un-boxes as required.

See [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) in the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Java SE 5.0 introduced autoboxing as a new feature. You can find more information in the Java documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html

Answer (score 3):

Java 5 and newer are able to perform [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).  The compiler will implicitly transform your code into:

```
int i;
Integer ii = new Integer(5);
i = ii.intValue();
```

Answer (score 2):

`i = ii;//no compilation error.`

Because this is called autounboxing. When you assign `object to primitive variable`, value from object is taken out and assigned to primitive. this process is called `autounboxing`. 
Vice versa is `Autoboxing`.

Answer (score 2):

This is called "autoboxing/unboxing". The primitive types like `int` are automatically converted to classes like `Integer` and vice-versa when it is needed.